# Need to store time field input as local time

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out how to make user input for a time field local.  I'm creating events in a form with a start_time and an end_time.  I'd like to bring in a time from a time field, and store the user's input as their local time.  I'd then like to convert it to UTC and compare it to Time.now.utc, in order to determine whether or not the event has started or ended.

I thought about converting the start and end times with start_time.localtime, and then adding/subtracting that from start_time (the default for time_field inputs is UTC), and storing that offset as a variable. Then add/subtract that offset from my stored times, and compare to Time.now (which the default is local).

This seems like much more work than is necessary, as I'm sure this is a common function that people need to use.  Is there some local_time_field implementation for forms that I haven't been able to find, or any other overlooked simple solutions?

Any input is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to get at the user's locale is in the browser, with JS. `new Date(userDateString).getTimeZoneOffset()` will return the user's offset in minutes from UTC. You can use that to convert the times to UTC before sending them up to the server. Of course, this won't work if you need to support JS-less users. Those users will need some other approach--you could make a "my time-zone" dropdown, for example.

Whatever approach you take, you'll have far fewer headaches if you only store times in UTC. Convert user-local times to UTC as early as possible in processing, and only convert back to the user's locale when you're about to display it. Otherwise you have to deal with not only time zones but also DST, and it's a huge headache.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was thinking the same thing.